# I need way to run a symbian application into the background

Tags: process, background, symbian

How may I run an application (designed by me) on my Nokia S60 #rd edition phone. Could someone direct me or if possible then explain here.

I need my application to run in background all the time without crashing and also it should invoke itself even after a restart - would that be possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If your application doesn't need GUI, create a console application. 
Check out this [basic example](http://www.symbiantutorial.org/symbian-tutorial/?3._Symbian_Fundamentals%3aStarting_a_Console_application). Also consider this when designing your application: [GUI vs Console](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/GUI_vs._Console).

As for the autostart feature, it's sure possible. Check out [this tutorial](http://wiki.forum.nokia.com/index.php/How_to_autostart_an_application_on_boot_up_in_3rd-_Startup_List_Management_API).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Also look up [RProcess](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Kernel_Architecture_2/RProcessClass.html). You could even have a second safety net process that is notified using RProcess::Logon() if the first one dies. The first could also be the safety net for the second :)